# Refresh Query in the background so that I can work on the Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Can tables be appended to each other any other way than using power query ? I have used power query to append 7 tables in my worksheet. however, each time the connection refreshes I have to stop working and wait on it to refresh. can it refresh in the background without disrupting my work or will it always refresh like that where I am unable to enter or select anything on the sheet while it is being refreshed ?

Comment: What kind of data source did you connect?

Answer (score 0):

In the Queries & Connections tab, right click on the Query and click Properties. The Query properties window opens. Make sure to **check the box** which say "Enable background refresh".

Sample screenshot below: 
[image: Query Properties]

Comment: that box, I am unable to tick or untick it. I don't know why

Comment: I guess Lee has already asked this above, but what is your source for the data?

Comment: the query appends 7 tables in 7 different worksheet

Comment: In that case I think you should be able to do it. Can you add a screenshot in your question along with the details of you Excel version?